# Automation error on CopyFromRecordset

Tags: excel, ms-access, dao

On the line where it says "sh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2"
i am getting an automation error on only one computer out of many (i dont know how many, but its at least 10+)
The query is just a basic parameterized query with the data source in SQL server, i included it at the end.

```
Private Sub export2()
If Not BasicInclude.DebugMode Then On Error GoTo Error_Handler Else On Error GoTo 0
Dim app As Object
Dim w As Object
Dim sh As Object
Dim iCols As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim e As Boolean
Dim s(4) As String
Dim v As Variant
Const xlCenter = -4108
Dim q As Variant
Dim qu As Long
Dim r As Variant
Dim t As Variant
Dim out() As Variant
Dim TidList As Variant
Dim rs() As ADODB.Recordset
Dim count As Long
Dim v2 As Variant
Dim counter As Long
Dim mem() As Variant
Dim DescGroup As Long
Dim ubrs As Long
Dim temp As New Collection
Dim TestItem As Variant
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Dim p As Object
Dim qry As QueryDef
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.ScreenUpdating = False
app.Visible = False
'app.ScreenUpdating = True
'app.Visible = True
Set w = app.Workbooks.Add()
```

Truncated this part out since its not pertanent

```
'Start'Resistance'Tester'Export'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Set qry = dbLocal.QueryDefs("qryResistanceData")
            qry.Parameters(0).Value = s(0)
            qry.Parameters(1).Value = s(1)
            qry.Parameters(2).Value = s(2)
            qry.Parameters(3).Value = s(3)
            qry.Parameters(4).Value = s(4)
            Set rs2 = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
            On Error GoTo 0
                With rs2
                If .RecordCount <> 0 Then
                    Set sh = w.Sheets(1)
                    sh.Name = TestItem(0) & " " & TestItem(6) & " " & TestItem(5)
                    'Build our Header
                    For iCols = 0 To rs2.Fields.count - 1
                    sh.Cells(1, iCols + 1).numberformat = "@"
                        sh.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs2.Fields(iCols).Name
                    Next
                    With sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(1, rs2.Fields.count))
                        .Font.Bold = True
                        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    End With
                    sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 1), sh.Cells(rs2.RecordCount + 1, 3)).numberformat = "@"
                    sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 4), sh.Cells(rs2.RecordCount + 1, rs2.Fields.count)).numberformat = "0.0000"
                    'Copy the data from our query into Excel
                    sh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
                    sh.Range("A1").Select
                    'Return to the top of the page
                    sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(rs2.RecordCount, rs2.Fields.count)).Columns.AutoFit
                    'Resize our Columns based on the headings
                    app.activewindow.splitcolumn = 0
                    app.activewindow.splitrow = 1
                    app.activewindow.freezepanes = True
                    w.Sheets.Add
                End If
                End With
```

still more code that doesnt have anything to do with the issue

```
    For Each sh In w.Sheets
                If sh.Name Like "Sheet*" And w.Sheets.count > 1 Then
                    w.Sheets(sh.Name).Delete
                End If
    Next
    If counter = temp.count Then
    w.Close False
    app.Quit
    MsgBox "No Data Found."
    Else
    app.ScreenUpdating = True
    app.Visible = True
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Please choose a part and test."
End If
Error_Exit:
Set app = Nothing
Exit Sub
Error_Handler:
If Not app Is Nothing Then
    If Not w Is Nothing Then
    w.Close False
    End If
app.Quit
End If

MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: " & Err.Source & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
Resume Error_Exit
End Sub
```

the resistance query

```
PARAMETERS tn Text ( 255 ), sns Long, sne Long, ds DateTime, de DateTime;
SELECT
           PartListTruncated.Truncated             AS PartNumber
         , dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.PartSN AS SerialNumber
         , PartListTruncated.TestType
         , dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.ResistanceTestDate AS TestDate
         , dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.Good
         , dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.Resistance
FROM
           PartListTruncated
           INNER JOIN
                      dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas
                      ON
                                 PartListTruncated.Part_Number = dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.PartNumber
WHERE
           (
                      (
                                 (
                                            dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.PartSN
                                 )
                                 >=[sns]
                                 And
                                 (
                                            dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.PartSN
                                 )
                                 <=[sne]
                      )
                      AND
                      (
                                 (
                                            dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.ResistanceTestDate
                                 )
                                 >=[ds]
                                 And
                                 (
                                            dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.ResistanceTestDate
                                 )
                                 <=[de]
                      )
                      AND
                      (
                                 (
                                            dbo_EPS_EPSResistanceTester_Meas.PartNumber
                                 )
                                 =[tn]
                      )
           )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I never ended up figuring out why it broke, but changing the recordset type from a DAO recordset to an ADODB recordset worked.

added

```
Dim f1 As DAO.Field
Dim rs3 As DAO.Recordset
```

changed

```
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
```

then i changed how i delt with the recordset.

```
Set qry = dbLocal.QueryDefs("qryResistanceData")
qry.Parameters(0).Value = s(0)
qry.Parameters(1).Value = s(1)
qry.Parameters(2).Value = s(2)
qry.Parameters(3).Value = s(3)
qry.Parameters(4).Value = s(4)
Set rs3 = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
If rs3.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs2.Fields.Append "PartNumber", adVarChar, 255, adFldKeyColumn
    rs2.Fields.Append "SerialNumber", adInteger, , adFldKeyColumn
    rs2.Fields.Append "TestType", adVarChar, 255
    rs2.Fields.Append "TestDate", adDate
    rs2.Fields.Append "Good", adVarChar, 255
    rs2.Fields.Append "Resistance", adDouble
    rs2.Open
    rs3.MoveFirst
    While Not rs3.EOF
        rs2.AddNew
        For Each f1 In rs3.Fields
            rs2.Fields(f1.Name).Value = f1.Value
        Next
        rs2.Update
        rs3.MoveNext
    Wend
    On Error GoTo 0
    With rs2
        If .RecordCount > 0 Then
            Set sh = w.Sheets(1)
            sh.Name = TestItem(0) & " " & TestItem(6) & " " & TestItem(5)
            'Build our Header
            For iCols = 0 To rs2.Fields.count - 1
                sh.Cells(1, iCols + 1).numberformat = "@"
                sh.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs2.Fields(iCols).Name
            Next
            With sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(1, rs2.Fields.count))
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.ColorIndex = 2
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 1), sh.Cells(rs2.RecordCount + 1, 3)).numberformat = "@"
            sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 4), sh.Cells(rs2.RecordCount + 1, rs2.Fields.count)).numberformat = "0.0000"
            'Copy the data from our query into Excel
            sh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
            sh.Range("A1").Select
            'Return to the top of the page
            sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(rs2.RecordCount, rs2.Fields.count)).Columns.AutoFit
            'Resize our Columns based on the headings
            app.activewindow.splitcolumn = 0
            app.activewindow.splitrow = 1
            app.activewindow.freezepanes = True
            w.Sheets.Add
        End If
    End With
End If
```